# Package Not Found Maven Compile Error on Mvn Clean Install

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, microservices

I have a micro-service based application that I am building out locally. I have a situation where micro-service A is depending on micro-service B and as such I have included B in A's pom as a dependency and there are no errors in the code and all of the classes are recognized. However, when I go to do a 'mvn clean install' command on A, I get the error where none of the packages in B are recognized as well as 'Cannot find symbol' for all of the classes from B that I am trying to use in A.

I have tried changing the execution goal of the maven plugin to 'repackage' in the pom of B like:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I have also confirmed that the JAR file is getting correctly built out to my local maven repository in my .m2 folder and made sure that the classes and code is contained there.

I also have tried breaking down the maven commands into sub-commands instead of just doing a maven clean install

**POM for MS A**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.oz</groupId>
    <artifactId>franchise-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>oz-franchise-api</name>
    <description>API for FRP</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- SPRING WEB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- DATABASE/JPA BACKEND -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- USEFUL TOOLS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- OTHER OZ DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oz</groupId>
            <artifactId>core-library</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**POM for MS B**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.oz</groupId>
    <artifactId>core-library</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>oz-core-library</name>
    <description>The core library for oz</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- SPRING BOOT -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- DATABASE/JPA BACKEND -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MYSQL DATABASE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.15</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- JAVAX VALIDATION -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- LOMBOK -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: If you build a micro service based on Spring boot you can't reused the resulting jar file as a dependency...

Comment: @Compilerv2 IntelliJ

Comment: @khmarbaise so would that mean I have to use the POM and set the scope to import?

Comment: No the scope is not the way. You have redesign your modules if you like to reuse parts of the code. As JF Meier already mentioned...

Answer (score 0):

If your two microservices both need a set of classes, put that classes into a separate (third) jar, build it as normal jar and use it as dependency in both.

Comment: So essentially, if module B is the core dependency for this micro-service A and more micro-services to come in the future, what I would need to do is just build out module B into a normal JAR library file and then add it to my local maven repo, and then just include that into the POM files just as I would do for custom JAR files that are not included on maven central?

Comment: Yes, this would be a sensible way to go.